# call client side script(javascript,jquery etc.) from C# page methods

Tags: javascript, asp.net, static, fullcalendar, pagemethods

i am using [**fullcalendar**](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) with ASP.net(C#) in my web-application so i made use of **PageMethods** to achieve server side behavior for removing and updating an event on calendar. everything works fine when i try update and delete events, i used inline delete icon to delete the events from calendar so clicking on this image div causes the event to delete from database but the changes are not reflecting at the same time on calendar UI i mean i have to refresh the page and the removed event is gone. so now i am willing to call the following code from **PageMethod**.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', $("#eventId").val());
```

Since PageMethodes are **static** so it does not let me call the above script using RegisterClientScriptBlock or something similar.

Would anyone please help me to call the above script from an static PageMethod decorated with *WebMethod* attribute. if anything's not clear please let me know.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is your code to handle the client-side click of the delete div?

Comment: That's not how the web works. Please. The server does not tell the client to do things, the server _returns data_ to clients and clients adjust.

Comment: +1 you are right got it and did it using client side only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it in the success callback of your PageMethod:

```
PageMethods.DeleteEvent($("#eventId").val(), function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', $("#eventId").val());
});
```